# How to get customer tax number from PAYPAL IPN message?

Tags: php

The customer is a test (business) facilitator with saved VAT number ( tax number, sales tax number, dont know what is the offical name of it in the paypal terminology).
There is no tax number in the reply message.

Comment: Please state your problem wit some code you have written.

Answer (score -1):

No need to know code for this question...
The answer is simple: impossible.
Now I am realize the Paypal dos not send back the customer tax number.